# Analytic continuation definition

Tags: complex-analysis

I've seen that analytic continuation is defined as: Let $f_1,f_2$ be analytic functions on $D_1,D_2$, respectively. If $D_1\cap D_2\neq \emptyset$ and $f_1(z)=f_2(z)$ for all $z\in D_1\cap D_2$, then $f_2$ is analytic continuation for $f_1$ to $D_2$ and vice versa.

How come there are no restrictions for $D_1\cap D_2$? If we take $f_1(x)=0$ and $f_2(x)=x$ and $D_1=(-1,0]$ and $D_2=[0,1)$, then the previous definition would suggest that $f_2$ is analytic continuation for $f_1$ to $D_2$, which is not true.

Shouldn't there be restriction for $D_1\cap D_2$ be an open set? Is the previous definition incorrect or am I simply missing something?

Example of an analytic continuation definition -
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AnalyticContinuation.html

Comment: at first, the restriction is that $D_1$ and $D_2$ are open disk

Comment: and the analytic continuation theorem is that if $D_1,D_2,D_3$ are 3 (open) disks such that $f_1,f_2,f_3$ are holomorphic on each disk, and $D_1 \cup D_2 \cup D_3$ is ***simply connected***, then $f_1 = f_2$ on $D_1 \cap D_2$ and $f_2 = f_3$ on $D_2 \cap D_3 \implies$ $f_1 = f_3$ on $D_1 \cap D_3$. proving it is only a matter of the Cauchy integral formula/theorem, expanding $f$ as a Taylor series on a disk intersecting the 3 others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typically it is phrased to require $D_1, D_2$ to be connected open sets. In the link you provide, this is implicit in calling $D_1, D_2$ *domains*. Then the intersection is also open, avoiding the problem you describe.

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.